# What does "be it" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, sentence-meaning

I googled about this "be it" thing and I found a little sth about it, I learned it's an old subjunctive inversion, but I can’t understand meaning of the sentence below:

> But such an “objective” account is not adequate to resolve the
> conflict—be it to resolve the conflict by defeating one side.

Comment: [Grammarly](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/be-it-to-your-doctor-or-even-yourself.3173240/) has the example _ It is the nurse who will advocate for you, be it to your doctor, family, or even sometimes yourself_ where 'be it to' means 'whether this is to'. But multiple alternative situations are required, which is not the case in OP's example. **Are you sure the quote is complete?**

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It's possible to have "be XXX" with just one situation, though the meaning is changed to "even if XXX"; e.g. searching for "be he ever so brave" turns out plenty of (mostly somewhat archaic) examples.

Comment: I'd read that (as it contains 'ever so') as 'no matter how brave he is'. Here again, the structure is different. _Be he XXX_. Be he alive (or be he dead). _Be YYY XXX._   I'd say OP's example is non-standard. But it would be helpful to see more context.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm not sure there's a huge difference between "ZZZ no matter how brave he is" and "ZZZ even if he is ever so brave"; I think the construction can be validly explained either way :) I disagree that there's a structural difference here - "be he" vs "be it" is merely a change of pronoun.

Comment: 'Even if he is ever so brave' doesn't even belong in a poor fairy tale. // 'Even if he is adjective' vs 'Be it a lemon (or ...)', ie noun. The to-infinitival (unbalanced) is even further away.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Please "@" when replying, (1) I disagree; "Even if he is ever so brave he cannot defeat the dragon" is hardly out of place in a fairy tale (you may not like the style, but that's a matter of taste :). (2) That feels like splitting hairs: either way it's "Be <pronoun> <complement>"; if you think the complement being a noun phrase makes a difference there are plenty of examples of "be he the bravest <n>".

Comment: @psmears I've found one example in a Google search for "be he the bravest". https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22be+he+the+bravest%22&ei=IT8ZYNmVLvaq1fAPqvGh8A4&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiZqsPck8vuAhV2VRUIHap4CO4Q8tMDegQIDxA1&biw=1320&bih=734 where a noun follows.